# Intersection of Sets and Probability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is this equation True or False? $P(A ∪ B)$ = $P(A ∩ (B ∩ A^c$)).

I believe it to be False, but I am unsure on how to handle the two intersections. I think it is false because $P(A ∩ (B ∩ A^c$) is 0. I drew a Venn Diagram to see what $B∩A^c$ is. That intersected with $A$ is nothing. How does one tend to handle the two intersections with parentheses like that? If it was written as $A ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$ I know you can use Distribution Law. But how do we distribute intersection with another intersection?

Comment: Intersections by themselves are commutative and associative.  $A\cap (B\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap C=B\cap (A\cap C)$ and since it is unambiguous we can write more simply as $A\cap B\cap C$, just like how multiplication is as well $a\times (b\times c)=(a\times b)\times c=a\times b\times c$ etc...  The same is true for unions by themselves.

Comment: Intersections are commutative and associative: $A \cap (B \cap A^c) = (A \cap B) \cap A^c = (A \cap A^c) \cap B$. So you are right that it is empty.

Comment: I encourage you to look at the related question of whether $P(A\cup B)=P(A\cup (B\cap A^c))$ which is possible might have been the intended question and a typo got in the way.

Comment: Glad to know I was right @angryavian. Thank you all.

Comment: And the question was not a typo @JMoravitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've the right answer for the first prompt, but you've got the wrong reason.

> I think it is false because $P(A \cap (B \cap A^\complement))$ is $0$. [You missed a closing parenthesis ')'.]

In fact, $P(A \cap (B \cap A^\complement))=0$ is a consequence of $P(\emptyset) = 0$, which is in the of the probability axioms, and $A \cap (B \cap A^\complement) = \emptyset$ is an observation from the Venn diagram to be proved.

As @angryavian points out, set intersections are commutative and associative, so you can easily prove that by some manipulation of the sets involved: you see $A$ and $A^\complement$ and you know that $A\cap A^\complement = \emptyset$, so when you rearrange the sets in "$A \cap (B \cap A^\complement)$", you try to rewrite it as "$A \cap (A^\complement \cap B)$" by applying the communtativity on $B \cap A^\complement$ first, and apply associativity to finish.